# Choosing the right opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to amplify a PWM [0..5V] voltage coming from the Arduino to about a [0..10V] (I don't know if I need 0-10V, but I need a little amplification) but I have to connect the output of the opamp to a very small load (100 ohms, even less) so I think I need a power amplifier that supports a high current output (several amperes, I think 2A or 3A maximum.)

I am really struggling to figure out on the Texas Instruments or Digikey catalog what filters I should set to find the one that is right for me. There are a lot of them and some you have to order, while for others the shipping is a few days. I need it in a short time.

I filtered by:

- high current opamp
- surface mount
- I will use a bench power supply, so no problem for the opamp supply.
- What else? Maybe the frequency?

In addition to asking you **what other filters** I should put in, I especially ask you to **link me the opamp** that is right for me.

Comment: If you're trying to step up a binary signal, consider using a simple logic translation IC or buffer. An opamp can amplify analog or binary signals, but will be more complicated if you only need to boost a high/low signal.

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the load?

Comment: a resistive/conductive fabric material which will be heated by the voltage coming out of the opamp

Comment: Do you have a 10 V (or 12 V) supply available? If so then the usual way would be to use a "logic-level MOSFET" to drive the heater.

Comment: @KaleM There are a few videos available on the subject, for example [MOSFETs and Transistors with Arduino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IG5vw6P9iY4), if you like that way of learning.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for your response. I don't need a mosfet or bjt to drive anything, but I just need to amplify the output voltage from Arduino. The problem is that I don't know which opamp to choose given the hundred-ohm load I have to connect to the output of the opamp itself.

Comment: At the Arduino there is a PWM signal 0 & 5V. Are you wanting to get a digital signal of 0 & 10V or you wanting to filter the PWM signal to an analog signal 0 to 5V and then amplify that by two? 10V 100 ohm = 0.1A not "several amps".

Comment: If you need to drive a heater with PWM then why do you need a filter? If the heater is 100 ohms when cold then it will be a higher resistance when hot. 10V on the 100 ohms produces 100mA that is too high for most opamps. A surface mounted Mosfet will do it.

Comment: Component recommendations are OT here, but I used the filters "High current op-amp" and 100-200 mA output and 12V, 15V, and 36V power, to get (among others) this $5 part: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7171.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1682198881499&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F -- But it is not really what you need. You just need an NMOS or NPN BJT (with base resistor) and a 10V supply.

Comment: @KaleM You apparently don't know what you need to solve your requirements, people are suggesting proper solutions but you insist on your original request of a wrong type of "solution" PLUS you are requesting a specific component model which is against the rules here. This question will be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While PWM suggests you require a digital solution, not analogue (no op-amp), your question calls for an op-amp, so that's what I'll answer. It's perhaps a bit overkill, and a expensive to use a power op-amp here, when you can use a regular op-amp (limited to 10mA output), and boost its current capability with a single cheap transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEqBcl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This arrangement is just a slightly modified classic non-inverting amplifier, the difference being that we take feedback from the top of the load RL itself, instead of the op-amp's output.

We also must swap the inverting and non-inverting inputs of the op-amp. It may look like positive feedback, but the signal inversion of common-source M1 makes it negative.

The gain of the system is set by R1 and R2, as per the usual gain equation for the non-inverting amplifier:

$$ \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = 1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1} $$

Here's an input (blue) going between 0V and 5V, and the corresponding output (orange, the voltage across load RL):

[image]

This setup does not violate the input voltage range of the amplifier, since it's never more than +5V, and never less than 0V.

Since M1 will have voltage \$V_{M1} = 12-V_{OUT}\$ across it, and will be passing significant current \$I=\frac{V_{OUT}}{R_L}\$, it will dissipate power:

$$ P_{M1} = (12 - V_{OUT}) \times \frac{V_{OUT}}{R_L} $$

This will be at a maximum when \$V_{OUT}=6V\$, so maximum power dissipation in M1 will be:

$$ P_{M1(MAX)} = (12 - 6)\frac{6}{R_L} = \frac{36}{R_L}$$

If this value exceeds 1W or so, you'll need to consider heat sinking (or better cooling) for M1.

Any power op-amp you consider will suffer the same heating, for the same reason - a voltage difference between power supply and output, coupled with a large current flowing. There's nothing you can do about this, unless you employ digital PWM, or some kind of DC-DC converter.

---

If this is to be a PWM controlled load, then *any* op-amp solution is probably inappropriate. Here's how you might implement a digital PWM solution, in which a transistor is used to switch either completely on or completely off:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5nB8B.png)</sup>

The voltage *across* RL is digital, either the full 10V supply (with M1's gate over +3V) or 0V (with M1's gate at 0V).

M1 dissipates very little power when settled in either state, but can get warm due to power dissipated during the transition between states, if the load is significant. You might need a beefier transistor, like the IRF530, if you expect load currents over ½A or so.

As I said, this is digital. The only voltages possible across the load are 0V, which happens when the Arduino output is at 0V, or the full 10V supply when the Arduino output above 3V or so. There's no in-between.

Also, if your supply is not 10V, then you can't get 10V across RL without additional circuitry. In other words, unlike the op-amp solution above, this circuit *requires* a 10V supply for your load, not 12V or 15V, for instance.

Comment: I simulated the circuit with the 2N7000 (no opamp) with these conditions: Vgs=DC sweep 0..5V , Vcc=12V and 100ohm load. I noticed that the current reaches a maximum of 116mA. If this value is too low and not sufficient for the load .. correct me if I am wrong .. this Id=116mA is (Vcc-Vdrain)/100ohm .. so I either increase Vcc (which I cannot do in practice) or decrease Vdrain. But decreasing Vdrain means choosing another mosfet? Right?

Comment: @KaleM The 2N7000 is not the right MOSFET for higher currents, you should use a device with sufficiently low \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ for your particular load.

Comment: Do you know where I can find .MODEL models to import into 'circuitlab'? There is the option "Import spice model" but I don't know where to find the .MODEL file. Thanks to your answer I just started to use this simulator and it is very educational!

Comment: @KaleM I've done a lot of searching on Google for those models too! I don't know of any repository, sorry.

Comment: How strange ... I have simulated your circuit on LTSpice with a dozen different mosfets (some with Rds(on)=0.001ohm .. some with 0.05 ohm and some even with 2 ohm) but in all cases I have 120mA on the load from 100 ohm on the drain. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @KaleM Well, 12V across a 100Ω resistor will get you exactly \$\frac{12V}{100\Omega}=120mA\$. You can't possibly get any more current than that, unless you increase Vcc above 12V or decrease the resistance below 100Ω. The only reason the 2N7000 only achieved 116mA is because its \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ was too high. But you are still limited to 120mA at best, without changing Vcc or R

Answer (score 3):

Since  your load is resistive you just need a switch, not an amplifier. Since it's thermal you don't even need to switch quickly. If you are implementing a controller, PWM directly is better anyway since power is proportional to voltage squared (op-amp), but power is proportional directly to duty cycle when the voltage is fixed (direct PWM with no filter). That means the parameters are more likely to be suitable over a range of setpoints and demands.

If you are using the 700Hz-ish (if memory serves) PWM from a 5V Arduino you could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU7aJN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 represents your load.

There are many other MOSFETs that could work, but it's essential that it's a logic-level MOSFET that is specified Rds(on) maximum for 4.5V or 5V Vgs.

R2 keeps the MOSFET from switching crazy fast, and R1 makes sure the MOSFET turns off reasonably quickly if the input is left open or high impedance (rather than drifting into partial conduction and possibly burning the MOSFET up).